# how to rsync only new files and directories?

Tags: linux, shell, copy, rsync

I have to update my old repo with newer files/folders from other updated new repo.
I do not want any changes to be done for existing files/folders in old repo.

Now, when I try to do this -

```
  rsync --dry-run --ignore-existing --exclude '*maven.repositories' --exclude '*CXP*' -ravh /new_repo_path/ /old_repo_path/
```

I get the list showing even existing directories. Old files seems to be ignored but not the directories.

Can someone suggest a better way or what's wrong here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: I think this question is not really off-topic. In particular, an `rsync` command of this complexitiy is nearly always part of a script, so from the OPs viewpoint, someone might well provide an answer, where the rsync is replaced by a sequence of statements in order to achieve the task.

Comment: @user3256114: Not sure whether I understand the question, but consider the case that you have an "old" directory, but within this directory you have a subdirectory which contains a "new" file - should this new file be sync'd, even one of its parent directories is "old"?